# Textmate - Unable to locate luac

Tags: macos, lua, textmate, osx-lion, luac

I installed lua bundle to Textmate, but when click on "check syntax" I get this error:

```
Unable to locate luac

To succesfully run this action you need to install «luac». If you know that it is already installed on your system, you instead need to update your search path.

The manual has a section about how to update your search path.

For diagnostic purposes, the paths searched for «luac» were:

/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

I have probably lua installed correctly, when I write "lua" to terminal I will get:
Lua 5.1.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio

Im running Mac OS X Lion 10.7.2

Where is the problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a line that you pasted up there:

```
The manual has a section about how to update your search path.
```

which indicates you need to update a path so TextMate can find lua.

Check out [the manual for TextMate](http://manual.macromates.com/en/shell_commands#search_path) and see if the answer becomes clear there.

Comment: You typed "lua" into Terminal and found that, but the error message is asking for luac.  Where is **luac** and is that in your PATH environment variables?

Comment: I type "lua" to check that lua is installed on my system... I dont know what exactly luac is, but I suppose it is some part of lua libraries...

Comment: [luac is the Lua compiler](http://www.lua.org/manual/4.0/luac.html).  So it's a binary that you should be able to find if you search in the directories installed by lua.  Find where luac is on your system, and then add that path to your environment variables.

Comment: So I found that file and add path, but it didnt work, so I copy this file to another directory(desktop) and add path to desktop and now it works! Thanks ;)